# FULLCALENDER SCHEDULER V5 : EVENT TITLE WRAP

Tags: css, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

Is it possible to add any among the following features in non-premium version of FULLCALENDER SCHEDULER V5?

1. Increase the Event height and wrap long Event titles inside the Event block
2. Increase the width of time line slots(in MONTH,WEEK,DAY views) so that the events will automatically fit inside to show up long titles

I was able to increase the event height using css settings, but couldn't wrap the content.

```
.fc-event{
        height: 70px !important;    //working   
}
```

Tried below css, Is it wrong?

```
.fc-h-event .fc-event-title {           
            white-space: normal !important; 
            overflow: hidden !important;    
        }
        .fc-v-event .fc-event-title {
            white-space: nowrap !important; 
            overflow: hidden !important;    
        }
```

Thank you

Comment: `non-premium version of FULLCALENDER SCHEDULER V5`...Fullcalendar Scheduler **is** the premium version of FullCalendar. It's not clear what you mean by the "non-premium" version? Do you mean just regular FullCalendar?

Comment: If so then which views are you talking about? Yes there are day/week/month views but there are different types of day and week, e.g. timegrid, daygrid, list. The CSS may be different for each one.

Comment: `Is it wrong?`...well did you test it? What was the result?

Comment: By non-premium, I meant the opensource Fullcalender scheduler. I have not paid for the same.

Comment: I want to make this change in all the views. For that , I edited scheduler.css as given above, but nothing changed. Is the class wrong? Or is it not allowed to add this feature? Because I found an option SlotWidth in FULLCALENDER V4 which is a premium option.   https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/slotWidth  With this, I can achieve my need

Comment: `By non-premium, I meant the opensource Fullcalender scheduler`...the functionality of scheduler is identical whether you have a commercial license or the open source license - that depends only on your circumstances. Functionality is only different if you don't include the premium functionality at all in your page and just use basic fullCalendar (which means you can't use timeline view or resources).

Comment: `I want to make this change in all the views`...you mean all timeline views? Or just all types of views i.e. daygrid, timeGrid, list, timeline? You probably can't expect the same CSS to work across all those view types, they are quite different in certain ways. Please just editnyotr question to make clear specifically exactly what you are trying to test it with.

Comment: P.s the upgrade guide explains that slotWidth was renamed as slotMinWidth in v5 https://fullcalendar.io/docs/slotMinWidth

Comment: Thanks for your comments ADyson. slotMinWidth I didn't notice. Thank you very much. It is working